# Syntax highlight for C #define constant

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I would like to differentiate syntax color for C define that acts as constant vs macro that is invoked with extra args.
So this would trigger it:
`#define VAR 10`
This wouldn't:
`#define VAR(x) (x * x)`

I'm looking for `syntax match CConst regex` solution that I can put in snytax/c.vim.

Thanks

Comment: It is really a matter of whether you can find edge cases or not, but the idea is very simple: `:hi def link CConst Special` `:syntax match CConst "^#define [a-zA-Z]\+\s"`

Comment: @r_31415 sounds like the start of an answer

Answer (score 1):

Strictly technically speaking, there isn't really a difference between a define that "acts like a constant" vs. a "macro": in both cases the C pre-processor essentially does a simple text replacement.

This somewhat matters because you can do all sorts of weird stuff with macros, to the point of building a kind of DSL.

That said, if we assume that a constant is `#define name value` and a "macro" is `#define name(params) [..]`, we can modify the default `cDefine` syntax rule, which looks like this:

```
syn region cDefine
    \ start="^\s*\zs\%(%:\|#\)\s*\%(define\|undef\)\>"
    \ skip="\\$"
    \ end="$"
    \ keepend contains=ALLBUT,@cPreProcGroup,@Spell
```

To:

```
syn region cDefineMacro 
    \ start="^\s*\zs\%(%:\|#\)\s*define\s*\k\{-}("
    \ skip="\\$" end="$" keepend 
    \ contains=ALLBUT,@cPreProcGroup,@Spell
```

The `start` is almost identical, except that I removed the `undef` match (as it's not needed here) and added `\s*\k\{-}(`. `\s*` will match whitespace zero or more times, `\k` matches any keyword character (from the `iskeyword` setting, `\{-}` matches that zero or more times non-greedely (`*?` in Perl regexps), and `(` matches a literal `(`.

I have not tested this super-extensively, but did a bit of spot-checking on the Vim codebase and it seems alright.

You also need to define a `:highlight` for this, and apply it every time a C file loads, for example in your vimrc:

```
augroup my-c
    au!
    au filetype c syn region cDefineMacro 
                \ start="^\s*\zs\%(%:\|#\)\s*define\s*\k\{-}\s*("
                \ skip="\\$" end="$" keepend 
                \ contains=ALLBUT,@cPreProcGroup,@Spell
                hi def link cDefineMacro Constant
                hi     link cDefine      Macro     " This is already the default
augroup end
```

This highlights `cDefine` (constants) as the pre-defined `Constant` group, and the syntax we added as `Macro`. You can see a list of predefined groups with just `:hi`, or you can set your own colouring with `ctermfg`, `ctermbg`, etc.

You can also stick it in `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` if you prefer (I personally like having everything in my vimrc, but others prefer separate files: your choice). You don't need the autocmd stuff in that case and can just use:

```
syn [..]
hi [..]
```

Comment: Thanks for descriptive answer. Since I wasn't able to make it work precisely as I wanted directly with `syntax match`, I ended up relying on ctags data. 
I will definetely try out your solution too. One question though. Does it only highlights constant name where it is #defined or on usage sites too?

Comment: Getting it to work on usage of CONSTANTS is basically impossible with Vim's highlight system @Vjekoslav, since all it does is apply a bunch of regexps. You need a more advanced script for that.

Comment: Yeah that's why using tags ended up being better solution.

Comment: Yeah, but you need to use ctags which not everyone does @Vjekoslav  You should probably post that as an answer if you have the time; it's fine to answer your own questions.